# DXA 1.2 Page Meta Data schema doesn't resolve KeyWords, Multimedia fields as proper value

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.2

When we have Page meta data schema and we have field with multimedia or text field whose value is derived from the Category/Keywords then  DXA 1.2 doesn't resolve them to the proper values, instead it has the hash value like below

**org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.KeywordImpl@6b4c37a1**
**org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.ComponentImpl@49d1c6b3**

DXA code below

PageBuilderImpl.java is the class and the methodName processMetadataField(final Field field)

```
        **final String fieldName = field.getName();**

        String value;
        **switch (fieldName) {**
            case "internalLink":
                final String componentId = ((BaseField) field).getTextValues().get(0);
                try {
                    value = linkResolver.resolve(componentId);
                } catch (SerializationException | ItemNotFoundException e) {
                    LOG.warn("Error while resolving link: {}", componentId);
                    value = componentId;
                }
                break;
            case IMAGE_FIELD_NAME:
                value = ((BaseField) field).getLinkedComponentValues().get(0).getMultimedia().getUrl();
                break;
            default:
                value = Joiner.on(',').join(field.getValues());
                break;
        }

        if (!(StringUtils.isEmpty(value) || result.containsKey(fieldName))) {
            result.put(fieldName, value);
        }
```

The switch case is on the field name. Then its restriction on the schema XML field naming, which is not generic implemenation

Comment: it is working fine in earlier version of dxa.net. Could you just debug it, using opensource DD4T code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution for the issue, Implemented in the generic way so that it would cater for all the scenarios and below is the code fix required. In the **PageBuilderImpl.java** is the class and the methodName **processMetadataField(final Field field)**

final String fieldName = field.getName();

```
    FieldType fieldType = field.getFieldType();            
    String value;
    // changed the switch on the fieldType rather on the field name
    switch (fieldType) {
    //removed the internal link String to COMPONENTLINK FieldType
        case COMPONENTLINK:
            final String componentId = ((BaseField) field).getTextValues().get(0);
            try {
                value = linkResolver.resolve(componentId);
            } catch (SerializationException | ItemNotFoundException e) {
                LOG.warn("Error while resolving link: {}", componentId);
                value = componentId;
            }
            break;
         // changed the image String to the MultimediaLink field
        case MULTIMEDIALINK:                    
          value = ((BaseField) field).getLinkedComponentValues().get(0).getMultimedia().getUrl();                    
            break;
         // added the new case for keyword field as this would have value in getTextValues
        case KEYWORD:
             value = Joiner.on(',').join(((KeywordField) field).getTextValues());
            break;
        default:        
             value = Joiner.on(',').join(field.getValues());                 
             break;
    }
```

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it :).